# Show $\left(1+\frac 1 x\right)^{x} < e < \left(1+\frac 1 {x}\right)^{x+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

I had to resort to the following characterization of number $e$ in order to [Proof $\sum\limits_{n \le k/2} \frac 1 n < \log k$ to show Pólya's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243054/proof-sum-limits-n-le-k-2-frac-1-n-log-k-to-show-p%C3%B3lyas-inequality):

> $\forall x > 0. \left(1+\frac 1 x\right)^{x} < e < \left(1+\frac 1 {x}\right)^{x+1}$

Unfortunately, I don't have this result yet in my theorem prover. What is an easy way to derive it?

Comment: Note that $e<\left(1+1/x\right)^{x+1}$ is equivalent to $\left(1-1/y\right)^y<e^{-1}$ where $y=x+1>1$. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: It all depends on what you have defined and proved for $e$ already.

Comment: The duplicate is essentially the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147269/proving-an-inequality-without-an-integral-frac-1x1-leq-ln-1x-ln-x)

Comment: Also note https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lower_Bound_of_Natural_Logarithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
 $\left(1+\frac 1 x\right)^{x}=e^{x\log (1+1/x)}<e^{x\frac 1 x}=e$

$\left(1+\frac 1 x\right)^{x+1}=e^{(x+1)\log (1+1/x)}> e$

Edit

If $F(x)=(x+1)\log (1+1/x)$

- $\lim_{x\to 0^+}F(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log (1+1/x)}{1/(x+1)}=1$, by L-hospital.
- $F'(x)=\log (1+1/x)-1/x$, How $\log (1+1/x)<1/x\implies F'(x)<0$ then $F(x)$ is decreasing in $(0,\infty)$

Therefore $F(x)=(x+1)\log (1+1/x)>1$

Comment: The first inequality is obvious, however,  the last inequality needs to be proven.

Comment: @dnqxt ok now I proof this.